# OlegDB in production

Tags: apache-2.2, database, nosql

When evaluating available NoSQL solutions, our team identified following product for evaluation: [OlegDB](https://olegdb.org/).

Site looks pretty decent and documentation is available. While site says it's production-ready ([here](https://olegdb.org/faq.html#3)), I'd like to know community opinion before giving it a try. I've planned to start with a test deployment on a low-end server (Debian Jessie running on Athlon 5600+, 4GB DIMM2) to serve data to about ~10-15 users concurrently online via our Apache HTTPD 2.4.

What would you say, is it worth to test it?

Thank you!

Comment: Signed for --> dba SE

Comment: oh! the internet